# Best way to call a Zend_Rest Action from another action controllers

Tags: api, zend-framework, rest, controller, action

I have set an "Api" module in my Zend (1.12) application who works with Rest.
So in that module the controllers extend Zend_Rest_Controller. It works fine and It's very useful using it from terminal or from ajax calls. Every Controller returns json.

Just a quick example of Rest Controller:

```
class Api_NewsController extends Zend_Rest_Controller
{
...
    public function postAction()
    {
        $param = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
        $news = new Api_Model_News();
        $insert = $news->insert($param['id']);
        $this->getResponse()->appendBody( json_encode($param) );
    }
....
```

using it from curl in terminal

```
curl -v http://example/api/news/123
```

using it from jQuery ajax

```
$.post("http://example/api/news", { "id": 123 },
    function(data){}, "json");
```

But now the target is to call that Rest **postAction** from another controller (from another module).
How is the best way?

Comment: can you explain a little what do you mean by calling Api_NewsController::postAction from another controller? you mean generating a url?

Comment: There is the postAction in a module called Api.
I want to call it from another controller...
something like...

     $var = $this->(something to take and return the postAction in var);

all this from another controller in another module.

Comment: if you find yourself using response from a different controller, consider having that login in a controller helper or in a model..

Answer (score 0):

You can use the View Helper "action": http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.action

Or do it the "proper" API way and use curl?